# LabelBinarizer gives all values zeros

Tags: python, deep-learning

I'm encoding my labels with label binarizer like this:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer

# Transform labels to one-hot
lb = LabelBinarizer()
Y = lb.fit_transform(df.classification)
```

But when I print Y I get all zeros like:

```
[[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 ...
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]]
```

I don't know if all the values in all rows are zeros or not. Unfortunately, I can't see the complete row and couldn't find a way to do so. Are these values right or not?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: sum the rows in the Y

Comment: I sum the rows in Y like: `import numpy as np

arr = np.array(Y)

print('rows:',  arr.sum(axis=1))` and got output like: `rows: [1 1 1 ... 1 1 1]`

Comment: Is this how hot encoding is supposed to work?

Comment: yes, there are a lot of zeros and 1 at the specific place. Please, refer to the LabelBinarizer documentation about the details.

Comment: I've already read the documentation but did not sure if its working fine or not. Because somehow the model's accuracy is not improving after some point so I decided to check the internal working.

Comment: so it's working fine? right?

Comment: probably it does